# XSL greater than and mod

Tags: xslt

I need to pull values out when at the following numbers (in a pipe delimited .txt file):

221
262
303
344
385
to infinity...

The pattern is 221 + 41(x), therefore the logic for the when needs to be when FieldNum is both greater than 220 and FieldNum mod 41 = 16.

How do I do this conditional?

This is what I have:

```
<xsl:when test ="$FieldNum &gt 220 and $FieldNum mod 41 = 16">
```

I'm getting an XSLT compile error when doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that's missing is the semi-colon at the end of the entity. You want "&gt;".